# select in form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

what i did:

```
rails g scaffold game optionselect:string
rake db:migrate
```

in my view inside the **form_for(@game)**:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :optionselect %><br />
  <%= f.select( :optionselect, "id", { "Option 1" => "1", "Option 2" => "2"}) %>
</div>
```

what i want to do:

select a value from the selectbox and save the selected value in **@game.optionselect**

problem: there are no selectable values visible. when i leave out the **f.** in front of **f.select** the values are visible but are not being saved (which i'm aware of).

Comment: Did you do what is described here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models ? So it would either : `select( :game, :optionselect, [["Option 1", "1"], ["Option 2", "2"]])` or `f.select(:optionselect, [["Option 1", "1"], ["Option 2", "2"]])` read carefully the red block about using the select for a belongs_to association if that's what you're trying to achieve

Comment: And by the way, I believe this is in a `form_for(@game)`, not `form_for(@games)` right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practise to keep such collections in the model and create class method to prepare them, ex:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  OPTIONS = [
    {:name => 'Option 1', :id => 1},
    {:name => 'Option 2', :id => 2},
    {:name => 'Option 3', :id => 3}
  ]

  def self.options
    OPTIONS.map{ |option| [option[:name], option[:id]] }
  end
end
```

then in the view:

```
= f.select :optionselect, Game.options
```

Comment: this gives me a syntax error "unexpected keyword end" so i changed it to **def self.options**