# Rails 4 form_for select tag wont persist when trying to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, form-for

So i am trying to implement a *dropdown* menu in my edit form for users, i used devise, so this edit form is inside my *devise/registrations/edit.html.erb file.*

first i get and error for undefined method for :optionselect (which seems understandable since i couldn't find this elsewhere other than this  [select in form_for rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790557/select-in-form-for-rails)
so this is wrong.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role %><br />
    <%= f.select :optionselect, User.options %>
  </div>
```

i also had it like this

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :role %><br />
  <%= f.select :role, [['Member', 'member'], ['Astronaut', 'astronaut'], ['Candidate',    'candidate']] %>
```

but no luck. because it wouldn't persist the changes i made when editing the role of the user.
Also the name doesn't persist when trying to update it. maybe that gives us a lead.

models/user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :books
      has_many :reviews
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable,
             :registerable,
             :recoverable,
             :rememberable,
             :trackable,
             :validatable
      validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
      validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
      validates :password,
                :presence => { :on => :create },
                :length   => { :minimum => 6, :allow_nil => true }
      OPTIONS = [
        {:role => 'memeber'},
        {:role => 'astronaut'},
        {:role => 'candidate'}
      ]

      def self.options
        OPTIONS.map { |option| option[:role] }
      end
    end
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def index
        binding.pry
        @users = User.all
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update!(user_params)
          redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @user
        else
          render :action => 'edit'
        end
      end

      private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role)
      end
    end
```

devise/registration/edit.html.erb

```
        <h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :role %><br />
        <%= f.select :optionselect, User.options %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
        <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
        <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Update" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <h3>Cancel my account</h3>

    <p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

    <%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.select(:role, User::USER_OPTIONS) %>
```

models/user.rb

```
USER_OPTIONS = ["memeber", "astronaut", "candidate"]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the post, this works to an extent, it allows me to have a cleaner code. Which is a plus, though i think im doing something wrong still since its not persisting when i change the role and click update in my edit form. @Deema

Comment: okay, in the "RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController" make sure that you add :role to the list of params.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me, I'm assuming that controller would be in controllers directory. I'm afraid i dont have a RegistrationsController unless its somewhere devise created behind the curtains. though i have :role in my users_controller.rb if that helps, @Deema

Comment: no no, you create it yourself. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller , http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html

Comment: ahh so looking at the link i searched for more info and came across this  http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html.. sweet stuff.. Thank you very much for helping me with this one. One less issue =) @Deema